# from Plain text generate encrypted text of same legnth

Tags: java, encryption

I want to create a java program in which I will give plain text , a key then the output should be of same length as of plain text. Using the same key I will decrypt the encrypted text. So please suggest me how to proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: Ciphertext is usually of the same length as the plaintext, plus a little bit of padding to get to the block size. Will that be good enough? Or does it need to be the exact same length? (Which I suppose means blocksize = 1)

Answer (score 1):

What sort of encryption scheme are you wanting?  The Vigenère cipher will give you ciphertext of the same length as your plaintext, but if the key is not random the ciphertext will be vulnerable to various frequency attacks such as the [Kasiski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasiski_examination) examination.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Its not a security related application. I just want to create a program in which I will enter a plain text and key and I will get the cipher text and I am able to decrypt with same key.

Comment: and also for different key I want to generate different cipher text

Comment: Even with a completely random key, Vigenere is dangerous if the key is shorter than the message or you use the same key twice (if you use the key only once and it is longer than the message, you have yourself a perfectly secure one-time-pad encryption).

Comment: My main aim is just to change a string to other string and when I want it again I can decrypt.

Answer (score 1):

Using a stream cipher like RC4 or a block cipher like AES in a counter mode can do what you want. However, these still require an a random IV for each message so you have to somehow manage that.

Comment: For a stream cypher like RC4 or AES-CTR the IV is often called a "nonce" (number used once) and can be shorter than an IV.